# Can I get multiple gold badges for a single question views?

Tags: support, badges

I got a gold badge to my question when it crossed 10k views, now again it'll go to cross 20k views, would I get one more gold badge for that?

[image]

It's written that, "This badge can be awarded multiple times." but I could find some question with 35k views and his questioner has the only single gold badge?

Please correct me if I understood wrong!

Comment: It can be awarded multiple times *for multiple questions*.

Comment: While what @CodyGray said is correct maybe "awarded multiple times for different questions" would make it clearer if it fits on the page.

Comment: I find "does it work the way I just saw it working?" to be a somewhat pointless question. You may want to rephrase that to ask what "can be awarded multiple times" means then (considering it doesn't appear to be on a per-question basis), assuming that's what you want to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Creating an answer that summarizes the comments and adds an explicit example)

> It can be awarded multiple times for multiple questions. –  Cody Gray
>
> While what @CodyGray said is correct maybe "awarded multiple times for different questions" would make it clearer if it fits on the page. –  PeterJ

What they mean is that while it's true that the badge can be awarded multiple times, *it is only awarded once per question*. If someone has two "Famous Question" badges, it will be because they asked two separate questions, each of which hit 10000 views. As you astutely noticed, posting one question with 20000 views nets one "Famous Question" badge, not two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I can understand what exactly that line means.

Comment: @Hemang Good to know I cleared it up for you :)